# ngrok forwarding url is not work in ms teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am build a MS teams bot from Bot framework SDK in python. I entered correct APP Id & Password in config file but still my ngrok forwarding URL is working I am not got any hits from teams but when I run it without APP id & password and send the requests from bot framework emulator it worked fine .

from [HERE](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/README.md) I downloaded the SDK.(BotBuilder-Samples\samples\python\16.proactive-messages)

[this is what error I got on ngrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnwqy.png)

Comment: Could you please check if the bot is also running on port 3978?

Comment: yes i already check this ..my bot is running on same port

Comment: And there is nothing after the OPTIONS/500 errors? The Teams channel is enabled correctly in the Azure bot's Channels pane?